# How will Entity framewrok determine the primary key in a database first approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I have the following three models classes inside my sql server 2008 , and i mapped the tables using ado.net entity framework :-

The primary key for the ITSwitchPort table inside the Database is is TechnologyID & SwitchID :

```
public partial class ITSwitchPort

    {

        public int TechnologyID { get; set; }

        public int SwitchID { get; set; }

        public string PortNumber { get; set; }



        public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }

        public virtual ITSwitch ITSwitch { get; set; }

    }
```

The primary key for the Technology table inside the Database is is TechnologyID:

```
public partial class Technology

    {

        public Technology()

        {

            this.ITServers = new HashSet<ITServer>();

            this.ITSwitchPorts = new HashSet<ITSwitchPort>();

            this.TechnologyAudits = new HashSet<TechnologyAudit>();

            this.TechnologyIPs = new HashSet<TechnologyIP>();

        }



        public int TechnologyID { get; set; }

        public string Tag { get; set; }

        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }

        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> TypeID { get; set; }

        public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }

        public Nullable<long> IT360ID { get; set; }

        public bool IsCompleted { get; set; }

        public Nullable<long> PartialTag { get; set; }

        public bool IsManaged { get; set; }



        public virtual ICollection<ITSwitchPort> ITSwitchPorts { get; set; }

    }
```

The primary key for the ITSwitch table inside the Database is SwitchID :

```
public partial class ITSwitch

    {

        public ITSwitch()

        {

            this.ITSwitchPorts = new HashSet<ITSwitchPort>();

        }



        public int SwitchID { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> ModelID { get; set; }

        public string Spec { get; set; }

        public int RackID { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> ConsoleServerID { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public long IT360SiteID { get; set; }

        public byte[] timestamp { get; set; }

        public string ConsoleServerPort { get; set; }



        public virtual SwitchModel SwitchModel { get; set; }

        public virtual Technology Technology { get; set; }



        public virtual ITRack ITRack { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ITSwitchPort> ITSwitchPorts { get; set; }

    }
```

Now if I try to update the ITSwitchPort.SwitchID, I will get an error that SwitchID is part of the key and can not be updated, so my queston is how entity framework determine what the Key for the above three models?

Comment: The error tells yo that you can't change the value of a PK field in the database. You shouldn't change the key value but *replace* the `ITSwitchPort` record by a new one.

Comment: so you mean that the error is from the database and not from the entity framework, and generally speaking how will entity framework determine the PK for my entities? will it use any name conversion or it can determine what are the PKs from the DB regardless of the key name ?

Comment: Yes, it's based on name conventions. EF sees that `ITSwitchPort` is a junction table between `Technology` and `ITSwitch`. The error is from EF, but you'd get a similar error if you'd try this in the database directly.

Comment: so what if i use different name for the primary key , where i have a table named PC where it have a primary key of SerialKey , so does this mean that when i map this table using EF, it will not be able to know the key ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All though your problem is solved, your question remained unanswered.

The question is, how does Entity-Framework knows that a property is the table Primary key - DbFirst.

The answer is that once you use database first, Entity-Framework automatically adds mapping between your entities and your tables, and one of the mapping is as follows :

```
this.HasKey(a => a.TechnologyID );
```

in the Technology mapping class . ( that was generated automatically )

With this code, Entity-Framwork knows which property is the primary key .

Comment: so you mean that it reads the primary key from the database regardless of the table name and primary key name ?

Comment: and in my case i can not find any tis.HasKey ? can you advice?

Comment: since you are using ADO.NET, just take a look in the generated .edmx file that EF created, you will understand it all. (the mapping in this case is there )

Comment: but my question is how the mapping inside the edmx is done ? will EF set the primary key for the models exactly as they are defined inside the database or it will use specific criteria. such as setting the first field as PK or set the field with TableName + ID as the primary key ?

Comment: Thus i told you to look into the edmx file and there you will find your answers . you would see there that EF maps between your primary key in your database (with the same name in the database) to the primary key in your entity ( this will probably also have the same name ), the names are usually different between the table name and the entity name ( pluralization ) . to see XML File : Right click on the edmx file -> Open With -> XML Editor and there you will see something like : <Key>    <PropertyRef Name="Id" />     </Key>

Comment: so this means that EF will set the primary keys for the entities (when using a database first approach) exactly as they are defined inside the database ? without relying on any criteria?

Comment: so this what i was asking about , and i am afraid that in the future i might have mismatch between the PK in the database and inside the .edmx file ...becuase i did not understand how the map is done